# Sed replace string, based on input file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

Wanting to see if there is a better/quicker way to do this.

Basically, I have a file and I need to add some more information to it, based on one of its fields. e.g.

File to edit:

```
USER|ROLE
user1|role1
user1|role2
user2|role1
user2|role11
```

Input File:

```
Role|Application
role1|applicationabc
role2|application_qwerty
role3|application_new_app_new
role4|qwerty_abc_123
role11|applicationabc123
```

By the end, I want to be left with something like this:

```
USER|ROLE|Application
user1|role1|applicationabc
user1|role2|application_qwerty
user2|role11|applicationabc123
user2|role3|application_new_app_new
```

My idea:

```
cat inputfile | while IFS='|' read src rep
do   
sed -i "s#\<$src\>#$src\|$rep#" /path/to/file/filename.csv
done
```

What I've written works to an extent, but it is very slow. Also, if it finds a match anywhere in the line, it will replace it. For example, for user2, and role11, the script would match role1 before it matches role11.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a quicker way to do this?
2. Is there a way to match against the exact expression/string? Putting quotes in my input file doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

With `join`:

```
join -i -t "|" -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -t '|' -k2b,2 file) <(sort -t '|' -k 1b,1 input)
```

From the join manpage:

> Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields.

That's why we need to sort the two files first: `file` on the first field and `input` on the second.

Then `join` joins the two file on those fields `-1 2 -2 1`. Output would then be:

```
ROLE|USER|Application
role1|user1|applicationabc
role1|user2|applicationabc
role11|user2|applicationabc123
role2|user1|application_qwerty
```

Comment: I was going to post this but it looked a bit of a mess, +1 anyway though :)

Comment: I get an error saying file1 is not in a sorted order.

Comment: @StevenFalzon How does file1 look? It must be sorted on the joined field.

Answer (score 2):

Piece of cake with `awk`:

```
$ cat file1
USER|ROLE
user1|role1
user1|role2
user2|role1
user2|role11

$ cat file2
ROLE|Application
role1|applicationabc
role2|application_qwerty
role3|application_new_app_new
role4|qwerty_abc_123
role11|applicationabc123

$ awk -F'\\|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}; {print $0 "|" a[$2]}' file2 file1
USER|ROLE|Application
user1|role1|applicationabc
user1|role2|application_qwerty
user2|role1|applicationabc
user2|role11|applicationabc123
```

Comment: This will also get you the title application `'NR==FNR{a[tolower($1)]=$2; next}; {print $0 "|" a[tolower($2)]}'`

Comment: ^^ True.. I hacked one of the files, assuming that it was a typo... ;-)

Comment: @anishsane Can you explain the command to me a little, and how exactly it works? :)

Comment: Also, after testing, it seems to only add a pipe to the end, and not add the application name.

Comment: Additionally, can I specifiy which field it should match on? Ie, in file1, there will be multiple fields, not just the two shown in the sample data (but it will always be in the last field).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$2;next}s=$2 in A{ $3=A[$2] }s' FS='|' OFS='|' file2 file1
```

or:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$2;next} $3 = $2 in A ? A[$2] : 0' FS='|' OFS='|' file2 file1
```

**Explanation**

```
 awk '
     # FNR==NR this is true only when awk reading first file

     FNR==NR{
                # Create array A where index = field1($1) and value = field2($2) 
                A[$1]=$2

                # stop processing and go to next line
                next
            }

   # Here we read 2nd file that is file1 in your case
   # var in Array returns either 1=true or 0=false
   # if array A has index field2 ($2) then s will be 1 otherwise 0 
   # whenever s is 1 that is nothing but true state, we create new field
   # $3 and its value will be array element corresponds to array index field2

   s=$2 in A{
               $3=A[$2] 
            }s

  # An awk program is a series of condition-action pairs, 
  # conditions  being outside of curly braces and actions being enclosed in them. 
  # A condition is considered false if it evaluates to zero or the empty string,
  # anything else is true (uninitialized variables are zero or empty string, 
  # depending on context, so they are false). 
  # Either a condition or an action can be implied; 
  # braces without a condition are considered to have a true condition and 
  # are always executed if they are hit,
  # and any condition without an action will print the line 
  # if and only if the condition is met.

  # So finally }s at the end of script
  # it executes the default action for every line, 
  # printing the line whenever s is 1 that is true 
  # which may have been modified by the previous action in braces

  # FS  = Input Field Separator
  # OFS = Output Field Separator

    ' FS='|' OFS='|' file2 file1
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little about these commands and how they work?